# I am getting this type of error while accessing data

Tags: json, angular

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
    import { GetDataService } from "../../services/get-data.service";
    import { user } from "../../models/user";
    import { FormBuilder,FormGroup,Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
    import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
    @Component({
      selector: "app-users-detail",
      templateUrl: "./users-detail.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./users-detail.component.css"],
    })

export class UsersDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  users: user;
  private routeSub: Subscription;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private getData: GetDataService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData
      .getDataById(this.route.snapshot.params.userId)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.users = data;

        console.log(this.users);
      });
  }
}
```

this.data variable contains JSON as

{
       id: 7,
       name: "iam",
       email: "roshan@gmail.com",
       country: "asad",
       city: "asdasd",
       phone: "1122",
    }

but when i try to access users.name i get  "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: Where are you accessing `users.name`? You haven't added it to your question.

Comment: you had created a model for users check whether name thing exists in the user model

Comment: i an accessing from the users-detail.component.html but it giving me error.

Comment: and here is the model export class user {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  country: string;
  city: string;
  phone: number;
}

Comment: <div>
  {{users.name}}
</div>

Comment: i think your html is rendering before you are getting data try to add a if condition to your html, like add a variable to be false initially and modify it in your subscription to true

Comment: sorry i am new to angular i dont know much about subscription or anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `users: user;` with `users = new user();`

This way you wont get the error but `users.name` will still give `undefined` till it is assigned some value

Comment: why do like this? when he is already assigning the value in subscription block. It doesn't make sense. In the view he should access the value like this: {{ users?.name }}

Comment: your solution works for the html part but in ts file users.name will still give undefined before assigning anything

Comment: So why would you even want to assign it anything before hand. That's pretty wrong practice and even in the TypeScript file why would you want to access anything before assignment and if there's any exceptions then he should have used try catch. This is how it should have been done and last thing what if the user wasn't a class but an interface then what you would have suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Try using users.name like this:

```
{{ users?.name }}
```

This probably is happening because you are trying to access it before it get's assigned. There's not much wrong with the above answer but assigning a value before hand by using new User() is not a good idea, why would you want to assign the value again and again, when it can be fixed just in the view by using ?
Hope this helps.